# May I get this robot arm to be controlled via drawing, not programming?

Tags: windows, electronics

I got a Omron Viper 850 robot arm with a spindle mounted with a cutter. It is controlled via EV+ programming (EV+ is a programming language used in the ACE Adept Omron software to move the robot).

The idea, initially, was to use it to cut some plastic car plates that goes inside of the car. But I have a bunch of different models of car plastic plates and now I am having a bad time doing a program for every plastic plate model that I have to cut. Each program takes 1~2 days to be ready and the curves are not perfect.

The question is if there is some drawing software that enables me to take a photo from the plastic plate, delimit the borders and gets the robot to cut it. Or at least, a software for this robot that permits make some drawings and get the robot to follow the path, alike a CNC machine being controlled by MACH3 software.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What OS should that software run on, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid software?

Comment: Hi... If it's worth i'd pay any software. Windows 7 or 10